# Change the color and shape of a bubble chart in excel based on value in different column

Tags: excel, vba, colors, bubble-chart

I have a spreadsheet with lots of data in it,  some of the data  is displayed in a bubble chart, the size of the points is also displayed correctly.

Now, I need to change the colour (and shape, but that for later) depending on the status of the data, which is displayed in row Z with values from 1 ( red) to 3 (green).

My VBA skills are really rusty by now and i can't figure out why the following code only changes the colour of the first point?

```
Option Explicit
Sub ColortheFingpoints()
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim srs As Series
    Dim pt As Point
    Dim p As Long
    Dim valRange As Range, cl As Range
    Dim myColor As Long

Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection(1)
Set valRange = Range("Z8:Z10")

    For p = 1 To srs.Points.Count
    Set pt = srs.Points(p)
    Set cl = valRange(p)

    With pt.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        Select Case LCase(cl)
            Case "1"
                myColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Case "2"
                myColor = RGB(255, 140, 0)
            Case "3"
                myColor = RGB(0, 128, 0)
        End Select

        .ForeColor.RGB = myColor

    End With
Next

End Sub
```

edit 1:

The problem seems to be that it only runs once and therefore only looks at Cell Z8 and not Z9 or the following

Comment: it is working for me. Try add  Debug.Print cl.Address & "   " & cl after Set cl= and check the immediate window.

Comment: This works fine for me. Are all of your numbers 1, 2 or 3? If not, then the colour won't change

Comment: Yes, I can see the change if I change the number in the first cell, but it doesn't matter what I put in the following cells it allways just changes the first.

Comment: @MarcinSzaleniec  The output just shows "$Z$8 2
$Z$8 2
$Z$8 2
$Z$8 2"

Answer (score 1):

Chris, try to change

```
Set cl = valRange(p)
```

to

```
Set cl = valRange.Range("A" & p)
```

I don't know, why your code is working, but this one shall be more human readable. Tell me if it works.

Comment: still gives me the same error, it reads the value of Z8 correctly, but the value of Z9. Can the "Next" part be negated by intendation?

Comment: indentation is for us, mortals. You however should type Next p for clarity. In the comment above you said that it always read Z8, never Z9. Maybe try to check your spreadsheet, if there are no hidden rows after Z8, or something, As I have said, your macro is OK on my computer.

Comment: No hidden rows or anything, but if I force the code to read "Z9" it overwrites the color of the point from row 8 ? which is definitely not what I want. Thanks for your time!